# How to play an m3u8 online radio file in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

I want to play an `m3u8` url with the Windows Media Player component in c#.

Why does this not work for me:

```
WMPlayer.URL = "http://headend1.iranseda.ir:8134/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/radio-avaa/radio-avaa-40k.m3u8";
```

Comment: m3u8 is a playlist file not a music file itself so you need to get the playlist and stream the files in the playlist

Comment: Tidied up language and markup in question.

Answer (score 2):

#### First sample

For to play m3u8 files you can use [WPF-MediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Player = new MediaUriElement();
    Player.BeginInit();
    Player.EndInit();

    Player.Source = new Uri("[YourPath].m3u8");
    Player.Play();
}

public MediaUriElement Player { get; set; }
```

#### Second sample

Here is another example using [Vcl.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet)

For this example, I created a console application and install NuGet packages:

- Vlc.DotNet.Core
- Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops

Download for win32 and win64 from download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/:

- libvlc.dll
- libvlccore.dll
- The plugins folder (you can remove the plugins that you are not using from that folder)

Put it to folder lib/x86 and lib/x64 in root folder of project.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vlcService = new PlayerVLCService();

        vlcService.Play(new Uri("[YourPath].m3u8"));

        Console.ReadLine();
        vlcService.Stop();
    }
}

public class PlayerVLCService
{
    private VlcMediaPlayer _vlcMediaPlayer;
    public PlayerVLCService()
    {
        var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
        if (currentDirectory == null)
            return;

        DirectoryInfo vlcLibDirectory;
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            vlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"..\..\lib\x86\"));
        else
            vlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"..\..\lib\x64\"));

        _vlcMediaPlayer = new VlcMediaPlayer(vlcLibDirectory);
    }

    public void Play(Uri playPathUri)
    {
        _vlcMediaPlayer.SetMedia(playPathUri, null);
        _vlcMediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _vlcMediaPlayer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, with other m3u8 this code works. I added another version of the solution to this problem.